# Accessing an object in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, object, mysqli

Currently, I'm trying to move away from mySQLi procedural to object oriented style.    So, I passed an object to a php file via the Jquery Post() function. 
 Below:

**JS file**

```
var newemployer = {
            newemployeremail:newemployeremail,
            newcompanyname: newcompanyname,
            secondpassword:secondpassword,
        };
    var employerdata = JSON.stringify(newemployer);
    console.log("in jquery: " + employerdata);
        $.post('api/employerprocess.php', {employerdata:employerdata}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

On the **PHP** side: I have this:

```
$employerdata = $_POST['employerdata'];

$data = json_decode($employerdata, true);
print_r($data['newemployeremail']);
```

I can access the object in the above, but I can't seem to get access to the values in the object using the `->` operator.

```
$accessed = $data->newemployeremail;
var_dump($data->newemployeremail);
echo $data->newemployeremail;
echo $accessed;
echo 'Hi';
```

The $accessed variable, var_dump, the echoing of the object each yield this error, last two statements have a NULL at the end:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I'd like to use the  `->` operator.   I don't get it.  Why can't I access the values in the object with the  `->` operator?

Comment: `json_decode($employerdata, true);` with `true` as second parameter, json_decode returns an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`true` as a second argument to [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) means "returned objects will be converted into associative arrays". Hence you're receiving array, not an object.

You need to either pass `false` to second argument to receive object or access properties using array syntax: `$accessed = $data['newemployeremail'];`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values as  an associative array

```
$data = json_decode($employerdata, true); 
// the true param in json_decode mean that teh result is converted  in associative array  
echo $data['newemployeremail'];
```

so you have an array  and not an object

then try assign the json decode without true eg:

```
$data = json_decode($employerdata);
echo $data->newemployeremail;
```